# Using React-table to filter rows based on meta-data

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I know how to filter rows based on content that is rendered in the table, but how could I filter (using useFilters) a table based on information which isn't shown in the table, but is available in the data-set?

I figure I could let react-table show the tags/meta-data in the table and just hide it with styling, but that seems not too good.

Example data:

```
{title:"Lesson One", author:"Joe", category:"math"}
```

Where `title` and `author` are shown in the table, but `category` is only used for filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for this isn't the most elegant, but perhaps you can adapt it to fit your needs. I used the react-table examples to do most of the boilerplate, so the fields do not match with the example fields you gave but hopefully you can adapt it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-ardinghelli-z7fc1?file=/src/App.js

*In summary:*

Any fields that you do not want shown you can hide on table creation by passing the `hiddenColumns` property an array of string IDs.

```
const {
  ...
} = useTable(
  {
    columns,
    data,
    initialState: {
      hiddenColumns: ["firstName"] // In your case, "category"
    }
  },
  useFilters
);
```

I obtained an array of hidden columns from the table instance (line 86)

```
// Obtain an array of the hidden columns so we can render the filter for them
const hiddenColumns = React.useMemo(() => {
  return allColumns.filter(
    (column) => column.id === state.hiddenColumns.find(
        (columnId) => columnId === column.id))
}, [allColumns, state.hiddenColumns])
```

Note however that the `allColumns` property returns a *flat* array of columns, meaning that if you have nested columns then it does not track that information, instead you will need to use the `columns` property and modify the filtering to match your column nesting (if tracking the nesting is necessary for you). [Ref](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#instance-properties)

Once I obtain the hidden columns I can render `Filter` for each of them, depending on if `canFilter` is true or false, followed by the visible columns. (line 111)

```
<thead>
  {hiddenColumns.map(hiddenColumn => {
     return hiddenColumn.canFilter ? 
       <tr key={hiddenColumn.id} role="row">
         <th colSpan={visibleColumns.length} style={{ textAlign: 'left'}}>
           {hiddenColumn.render('Filter')}
         </th>
       </tr> : null
     })}
     {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
       <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
         {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
           <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
             {column.render('Header')}
             <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}</div>
           </th>
         ))}
      </tr>
   ))}
</thead>
```

You can obviously change the positioning of where the filter for hidden columns is rendered to suite your needs.

Also I will mention that the hook [useGlobalFilter](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useGlobalFilter) searches on hidden columns, so if you were looking for a global filter solution then it should work without any workarounds.